# How to get data json using afnetworking

Tags: ios, json, afnetworking

I want get array name "journals" from json . But NSLog return null .Whats wrong in the following code? Please help !
JSon API pic :

[image]

Code get data json using afnetworking:
[image]

Comment: what the result you get in `data`

Comment: Do not post a screenshot of your code. Copy/Paste it. What's the log of `responseObject`?